# Dictation Problem: What is the time signature?

Tags: arranging

So this is a song that I am trying to dictate so that I can play it as a duet with my cello teacher (the Briar and the Rose by Tom Waits). However, the time that we used when I sang it with my friends is not the time on the album and I cannot for the life of me transcribe the time.  Can someone for the love of "Bob" help me with this?

[Me singing it with the time we did](https://youtu.be/fIOWzLD7q9Y)

Comment: What do *you* (and teacher) think it's in?

Comment: You're singing it fine, but in a way that disguises the time: especially at the beginning, where you're rushing the words. That's good, stylistically, but if you want to write it down you'll have to sing it more regularly: more like a nursery rhyme. Get yer foot stamping slowly and regularly on "fell", "sleep", "by" and "stream". Each stamp is the start of a 3/4 bar. It starts:  I| fell - a|sleep - down|by - a|stream -  Words followed by a dash are minims. The rest are crotchets. The vertical lines are barlines. Got it? Nice song btw.

Comment: Btw, we're not meant to do this kind of stuff in here. I think you're allowed to ask in the Music Fans group though.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - often - as here, 3/4 could be confused with 6/8. And with a song sung with much rubato - again, as here - there's no real knowing what an actual appropriate time sig. could be. Think 'On Ilkley Moor...'

Comment: @Tim: 3/4 **IS** an appropriate time signature. It _might_ not be the one Waits used, but it's adequate. And it's easier for me to explain, and easier for the OP to understand than 6/8. He might not know much music theory, and may not _need_ to. His cello-teacher can always rewrite it in 6/8 if s/he feels strongly about it. But why _would_ they? And why - in the name of all that's decent - do you want me to think 'On Ilkley Moor'? :-)

Comment: Adam, maybe you could get this reopened by making your question more general initially, and then mentioning the song you've been struggling with, as an example.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, et al. - The main meter I was seeing online was 4/4, ha ha, so I guess meter is in the eye of the beholder.  If OP comes back, it's quite possible they will go for the sheet music, as an internet search might not have occurred to them earlier. / I think that little projects like this are great motivation for studying music theory. / If this is truly OP's first encounter of 6/8, then this would be a great time to get acquainted with it.

Comment: Adam, I suggest editing your question to make it general, with your song as a for instance.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - for starters, Ilkley Moor has the same sort of rubato  stops and starts - making a time sig almost insignificant. For seconds not having seen (or wanting/needing to) any written music for this, it has far moor (sic) of a 6/8 feel than 3/4. If anything. 6/8 and 3/4 have only a fleeting flirtation in reality.

Comment: No worries; I actually figured it out anyway.  When I did it with a bunch of meter changes but keeping the eighth note constant, it locked right into place.

Comment: @aparente001 I've actually played piano for 25 years and have a solid background in theory; I just could not find a consistent pulse because there isn't one.

Comment: @tim: Ilkley Moor has been sung many different ways over the years. The version you know may have rubato and stops and starts, but the version I know best - the one my relatives in Yorkshire sang fifty years ago - had _none_. They didn't like being asked to sing it as it was considered a bit of a Yorkshire cliche. It was in 4/4. (And yes, you could also choose to write it in common, cut common or 2/2 depending on a combination of the tempo and the perceived emphasis of the 3rd crotchet of the bar.) Not that their version was 'right' - folk songs get interpreted differently to suit the age.

Comment: @Adam Gluntz: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Tim: And thanks for telling me about 3/4 and 6/8. My gran is needing some help with her egg-sucking when you've got a minute ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could notate this in 6/8.  The best way to figure out the meter, and the note values, is to conduct while you are singing, or while you're listening to your recording.  You could have the downward beat on 1, and bring your arm back up on 4 (there being six eighth-notes in a measure).  Then the most common figure in this song will be quarter, eighth, quarter, eighth, in a lilting style.

You could look at a score for a similar tune while listening to it, to familiarize yourself with the meter, and to get more comfortable with conducting.

Note, after I wrote the above, I looked for sheet music online for this song.  I found two ways of notating it, both totally different from what I proposed.  But I went with what I was hearing.  (It did seem as though your first measure or two were in a faster tempo.)

Comment: I went through it again a few hours later and realized that there are a bunch of metric modulations with the eight note remaining constant (and some rubato).

Comment: @Adam Gluntz: Waits's version or yours?